# Shared toolbar items in SwiftUI NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a navigation stack that's about three views deep. I want every single destination in this stack navigation to all have exactly the same toolbar items, a "Skip" button at the top right corner. However I can't for the life of me find a way to apply that button once at the top level and have it propagate down to the children. I understand that in SwiftUI, you add modifiers like `.navigationTitle` to the child views and they search up the view hierarchy but is there really no way to do the opposite?

What I want would ideally look like

```swift
NavigationStack {
    RootView()
}
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
            Button(action: {}) { Text("Skip") }
        }
    }
```

But with how SwiftUI works I have to apply that on *every single child view*. Really? There's not a better way?

Comment: Just inherit the View?

Comment: Inherit? SwiftUI views don't use inheritance.

Comment: @ElTomato are you talking about creating some shared protocol or modifier for these subviews that they all conform to or use? That's exactly the same problem because I would still have to tag each individual view with it. What I want to do is apply bar items _that will never change_ across the entire navigation stack.

Comment: `NavigationStack` should be at the top of the app. there are few exceptions to this such as `TabView` and `sheet`. You can't nest them.

Comment: I'm not trying to nest them...I have a single navigation stack that I want to have the same bar item for all the views that are pushed on to that stack. I don't want to have to have each individual view define its own toolbar; I want to define it once at the top level of the navigation stack. For example, let's say I'm building a welcome flow. At the top corner of every screen in this flow is a button that says "Skip" so the user can skip the entire thing. I don't want to have to define that Skip button or attach it to child views in multiple places.

Who said anything about nesting?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `.toolbar {...}` **inside** the `NavigationStack`, just after the `RootView()`

Comment: Again, that a) does not propagate across the entire navigation stack and b) because it doesn't propagate, you have to put that on all the subviews, which defeats the purpose. I think the answer is, it's just not possible in the way that I want to do it.

Comment: I added the same modifier to each view on the stack and got several versions of the buttons. But without no button. Did you get anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

Normally you would just make a View and use it in each place but in this case I think you need a [ViewModifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier) like this:

```
struct MyToolBar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {}) {     Text("Skip") }
            }
        }
     }

}
```

Use in multiple places like:

```
NavigationStack {
    RootView()
    .modifier(MyToolBar())
}
```

Comment: But that's still the same problem, just hiding it in a modifier. I want to apply it once at the top level, whereas with a modifier, I'd have to tag each screen in the navigation flow. I think the answer, unfortunately, is it's not possible currently in SwiftUI.